# Create a small circle in excel POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I know this question might seem similar but I have different problem. I know how to create a circle or a shape. This is what I want to create

[image]

A little circle in the center of the excel cell

The circle that I am able to make, looking at tutorials etc is:

[image]

This is the code I am using to create:

```
      CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
       Drawing drawing = worksheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

       ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

       anchor.setCol1(0);
       anchor.setRow1(0); 
       anchor.setCol2(1);
       anchor.setRow2(1); 
       anchor.setDx1(255);
       anchor.setDx2(255);
       anchor.setDy1(0);
       anchor.setDy2(0);

       XSSFSimpleShape shape = ((XSSFDrawing)drawing).createSimpleShape((XSSFClientAnchor)anchor);
       shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.FLOW_CHART_CONNECTOR);
       shape.setFillColor(255, 0, 0);
```

I think there is something to do with the dx1,dx2,dy1,dy2 but setting any value in there has no effect.

I need to make that shape smaller somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the shape shall within one cell only then the anchor must also be only one cell. The positioning is done then with `Dx` and `Dy`. But the measurement unit is special. It is `EMU`  English Metric Units.

So the positioning of an ellipse in cell `A1` will be like so:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


class CenterShapeInCell {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   row.setHeight((short)(20*20));
   sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 20*256);

   CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
   Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

   ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

   //set anchor to A1 only
   anchor.setCol1(0);
   anchor.setRow1(0); 
   anchor.setCol2(0);
   anchor.setRow2(0); 

   //get the cell width of A1
   float cellWidthPx = sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels(0);
System.out.println(cellWidthPx);

   //set wanted shape size
   int shapeWidthPx = 20;
   int shapeHeightPx = 20;

   //calculate the position of left upper edge
   float centerPosPx = cellWidthPx/2f - (float)shapeWidthPx/2f;
System.out.println(centerPosPx);

   //set the position of left edge as Dx1 in unit EMU
   anchor.setDx1(Math.round(centerPosPx * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL));

   //set the position of right edge as Dx2 in unit EMU
   anchor.setDx2(Math.round((centerPosPx + shapeWidthPx) * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL));

   //set upper padding
   int upperPaddingPx = 4;

   //set upper padding as Dy1 in unit EMU
   anchor.setDy1(upperPaddingPx * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL);

   //set upper padding + shape height as Dy2 in unit EMU
   anchor.setDy2((upperPaddingPx + shapeHeightPx) * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL);

   XSSFSimpleShape shape = ((XSSFDrawing)drawing).createSimpleShape((XSSFClientAnchor)anchor);
   shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.ELLIPSE);
   shape.setFillColor(255, 0, 0);


   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("CenterShapeInCell.xlsx");
   workbook.write(fileOut);
   fileOut.close();

  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }
 }
}
```

Looks like: [image]

---

But I suspect what you really want is a conditional formatting with traffic light symbols like so:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class ConditionalFormattingIconSet {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

   CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   //cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER); // old apache poi versions
   cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER); // current apache poi version 4.1.0
   //cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER); // old apache poi versions
   cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER); // current apache poi version 4.1.0

   Cell cell;

   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cell = sheet.createRow(i).createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue(1+i);
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
   }

   SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

   ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(IconMultiStateFormatting.IconSet.GYR_3_TRAFFIC_LIGHTS);

   rule.getMultiStateFormatting().setIconOnly(true);

   ConditionalFormattingRule [] cfRules = {rule};

   CellRangeAddress[] regions = {CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:A3")};

   sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, cfRules);

   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ConditionalFormattingIconSet.xlsx");
   workbook.write(fileOut);
   fileOut.close();

  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }
 }
}
```

Looks like: [image]

Comment: The traffic light symbols was what I was looking for. From what I can understand the ConditionalFormattingRule will contain the rules for green, yellow and red circles.

Comment: Axel which poi version are you using? With poi 3.14 the function calls you have listed are not available

Comment: I am using poi-3.14 and I've tested it. Be exact please. What function calls are not available for you?

Comment: ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(IconMultiStateFormatting.IconSet.GYR_3_TRAFFIC_LIGHTS);

the library I have doesnt have any parameter with icon set. They take string as an input

Comment: [ConditionalFormattingRule createConditionalFormattingRule(IconMultiStateFormatting.IconSet iconSet)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/SheetConditionalFormatting.html#createConditionalFormattingRule(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IconMultiStateFormatting.IconSet)) Please download from https://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.14