# How to display Traffic Lights icons in a cell according to a boolean?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to display in a cell a green traffic light if `value` is `true` and red traffic light is `value` is `false`.

I read several documentation about `ConditionalFormattingRule` but I don't understand how it works...

**Algo wished**

```
...
Cell cell = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(5)
if (value) {
    cell.setIcon(TRAFFIC_LIGHT_GREEN)
}
else {
    cell.setIcon(TRAFFIC_LIGHT_RED)
}
...
```

Someone can help me to understand that please?

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Comment: Are you getting any error? Or the cells are just white, without the icons?

Comment: No because I don't understand how to do that. That's why I need some help.

Comment: `cell.setIcon(...)` without boolean also not working? Or you need help to put an Icon in excel Cell?

Comment: `cell.setIcon(...)` is not a valid method in apache poi. You would need to work with `CellStyle` and set the `FillForegroundColor`

Comment: @procrastinator Yes I need help to put the icon in the Excel cell.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes it is not valid, it is only for the example. Is it possible to add an icon in `FillForegroundColor` method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38763554/create-a-small-circle-in-excel-poi/38772101#38772101

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a small circle in excel POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38763554/create-a-small-circle-in-excel-poi)

Comment: I already saw this post. However, how define the rule for true or false? This is what I don't understand... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IconMultiStateFormatting` has following thresholds per default:

1. If the cell value is greater than or equal 67% of all the values in
   the range, then green.
2. If the cell value is lower but greater than or equal 33% of all the
   values in the range, then yellow.
3. If the cell value is lower than 33% of all the values in the range,
   then red.

If you need other thresholds, then you have to change that default.

Following code sets following thresholds:

1. If the cell value is greater than or equal 1 then green.
2. If the cell value is lower but greater than or equal 0, then yellow.
3. If the cell value is lower than 0, then red.

Complete Example using current `apache poi 4.1.0`:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class ConditionalFormattingIconSet {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

  CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER); 
  cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER); 

  Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue(-1);
  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

  SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

  ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(IconMultiStateFormatting.IconSet.GYR_3_TRAFFIC_LIGHTS);

  //rule.getMultiStateFormatting().setIconOnly(true);

  IconMultiStateFormatting iconMultiStateFormatting = rule.getMultiStateFormatting();
  ConditionalFormattingThreshold[] thresholds = iconMultiStateFormatting.getThresholds();
  if (thresholds.length == 3) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ConditionalFormattingThreshold threshold = thresholds[i];
System.out.println(i + " : " + threshold.getRangeType()); // default 
System.out.println(i + " : " + threshold.getValue()); // default
    // changing the thresholds
    if (i == 0) {
     threshold.setValue(0d);
    } else if (i == 1) {
     threshold.setRangeType(ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.NUMBER);
     threshold.setValue(0d);
    } else if (i == 2) {
     threshold.setRangeType(ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.NUMBER);
     threshold.setValue(1d);
    }
   }
  }

  ConditionalFormattingRule [] cfRules = {rule};

  CellRangeAddress[] regions = {CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:A1")};

  sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, cfRules);

  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ConditionalFormattingIconSet.xlsx");
  workbook.write(fileOut);
  fileOut.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I'm facing this error : `No such property: IconMultiStateFormatting`

Comment: @N. Lamblin: What `apache poi` version are you using? The code works for me using the current `apache poi 4.1.0`.

Comment: To be honest I'm using Katalon (Automation tool) and I didn't import anything. So I suppose that I'm using the apache poi version corresponding to Java 8 (Java installed on my computer). I will try to import apache poi 4.1.0

Comment: @N. Lamblin: Then I cannot help. The `IconMultiStateFormatting` is there since `apache poi 3.13`. So you would must use a really ancient version of `apache poi`. But also the error message `No such property: IconMultiStateFormatting` is confusing me. `IconMultiStateFormatting` is not a property but an interface. Where exactly is that error thrown?

Comment: Indeed, my software use `apache poi 3.9`. I guess that this is the problem... I have to find a way to use the new version. Thanks for your answer. I will try and will I come back to gove you a feedback.

Comment: I cannot have apache poi >= 3.13 with the current version of my software... So, I accept your answer anyway.